# Firebase App Indexing Privacy and Collected Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

According to Google docs for Firebase App Indexing:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/

*"A note about privacy: The personal content index only exists on the user’s device. None of the user’s personal content is uploaded to Google servers, and it only remains on the device while the app is installed.
However, aggregated statistics about apps' usage of App Indexing and other system health information may be uploaded to Google servers. To view or delete any of the actions on public content you’ve logged in your app, users can go to"* (See screenshot below)

My question here is about the collected aggregated statistics from android app clients? Are the collected data anonymous or they contain user related information? I'm asking this question since docs does not state any details about Firebase app indexing collected data.

Thanks

[image]